# Problem with mod_rewrite and relative paths of included css, js, image,... files and links

Tags: mod-rewrite, relative-path

First of all - I have searched quite a bit for an answer in stackoverflow and via google but haven´t been successfull so far to find a possible solution any advice would be greatly appreciated.

### problem is:

I have a page
*www.mypage.com*
and controll the language displayed via a GET parameter lang
-> *www.mypage.com/index.php?target=1&lang=en*

Now a client has registered a domain at *united-domains* (*www.mypage.it*) and wants me display the italian version of the page whenever the domain *www.mypage.it* is requested.

The provider *united-domains* offers a solution called URL-HIDING which basically seems to pass the the request to a URL+folder structure I provide (like *www.mypage.com/lang/it* - according to the specifications of united-domains it has to be a folder structure and may not be a file)

### solution so far:

Calls to the domain: *www.mypage.it* will be maped to *www.mypage.com/lang/it/* via the URL-HIDING option.

there an .htaccess file rewrites the REQUESTS to the actual target:

```
RewriteEngine on

## check if query string contains NOT 'lang=' 
## (lang might be changed by user after initial request)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang=
## redirect to page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mypage.com/index.php?target=1&lang=it

## check if query string contains 'lang='
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=
## Keep the existing query string using the Query String Append flag 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mypage.com/index.php? [QSA]
```

Problem is of course: the CSS, javascript, image,... files are included with an relative path

```
<link href="scripts/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="scripts/media.js" type="text/javascript">

<img src="images/logo.jpg">
<a href="download/test.pdf">PDF</a>
```

therfore the relative request *scripts/style.css* is mapped to *http://www.mypage.com/lang/it/scripts/style.css*

I am sadly stuck the the URL-HIDING mechanism of united-domains and changing every relative path the */scripts/media.js* is not an option as I´d have to change quite a bit of code.

Does anyone have a solution for this (my .htaccess knowledge is not the best I am afraid)
Couldn´t I just remove *lang/it/* from EVERY request and additionally check if the QUERY_STRING contains the string *lang=* and if it does simple add *?lang=it*

thanks to all that have taken the time to read so far - if anyone has a suggestion I´d be more than grateful !

stay well,
matthias

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick !

in folder:
**www.mypage.com/lang/it/**

I put:

```
RewriteEngine on
##  redirect if just folder is requested
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/lang/it/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mypage.com/index.php?target=1&lang=it

##  otherwise redirects if file does not exist
RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/lang/it/$1  !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mypage.com/$1 [QSA]
```